# Convert Microsoft Project Oxford Speech Recognition from Objective-C to SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

[Microsoft Project Oxford](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613452.aspx) has a nice Speech Recognition API and instructions for Objective-C on IOS. I build it easily following the getting started instructions. However, I am having hard time to convert it to Swift language.

I created a swift project first.  I created the bridge header file (ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h) and inserted following code to this file:

```
#import "SpeechRecognitionService.h"
```

I want to convert Objective-C both header and implementation files into  ViewController.swift.

contents of ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SpeechRecognitionService.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SpeechRecognitionProtocol>
{
NSMutableString* textOnScreen;
DataRecognitionClient* dataClient;
MicrophoneRecognitionClient* micClient;
SpeechRecognitionMode recoMode;
bool isMicrophoneReco;
bool isIntent;
int waitSeconds;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* startButton;

/* In our UI, we have a text box to show the reco results.*/
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView* quoteText;

/* Action for pressing the "Start" button */
-(IBAction)startButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

contents of ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

@interface ViewController (/*private*/)
/* Create a recognition request to interact with the Speech Service.*/
-(void)initializeRecoClient;
@end

NSString* ConvertSpeechRecoConfidenceEnumToString(Confidence confidence);

/* The Main App */
@implementation ViewController

/* Initialization to be done when app starts. */
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textOnScreen = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 1000];
    recoMode = SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase;
    isMicrophoneReco = true;
    isIntent = false;
    waitSeconds = recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase ? 20 : 200;
    [self initializeRecoClient];
}

/* Called when a partial response is received. */
-(void)onPartialResponseReceived:(NSString*) response
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textOnScreen appendFormat:(@"%@\n"), response];
        self.quoteText.text = response;
    });
}

/* Called when a final response is received. */
-(void)onFinalResponseReceived:(RecognitionResult*)response
{
    bool isFinalDicationMessage = recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_LongDictation &&
    (response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus_EndOfDictation ||
     response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus_DictationEndSilenceTimeout);
    if (isMicrophoneReco && ((recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage)) {
        [micClient endMicAndRecognition];
    }

    if ((recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self startButton] setEnabled:YES];
    });
    }
}

NSString* ConvertSpeechErrorToString(int errorCode)
{
switch ((SpeechClientStatus)errorCode) {
    case SpeechClientStatus_SecurityFailed:         return @"SpeechClientStatus_SecurityFailed";
    case SpeechClientStatus_LoginFailed:            return @"SpeechClientStatus_LoginFailed";
    case SpeechClientStatus_Timeout:                return @"SpeechClientStatus_Timeout";
    case SpeechClientStatus_ConnectionFailed:       return @"SpeechClientStatus_ConnectionFailed";
    case SpeechClientStatus_NameNotFound:           return @"SpeechClientStatus_NameNotFound";
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidService:         return @"SpeechClientStatus_InvalidService";
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidProxy:           return @"SpeechClientStatus_InvalidProxy";
    case SpeechClientStatus_BadResponse:            return @"SpeechClientStatus_BadResponse";
    case SpeechClientStatus_InternalError:          return @"SpeechClientStatus_InternalError";
    case SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationError:    return @"SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationError";
    case SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationExpired:  return @"SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationExpired";
    case SpeechClientStatus_LimitsExceeded:         return @"SpeechClientStatus_LimitsExceeded";
    case SpeechClientStatus_AudioOutputFailed:      return @"SpeechClientStatus_AudioOutputFailed";
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneInUse:        return @"SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneInUse";
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneUnavailable:  return @"SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneUnavailable";
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneStatusUnknown:return @"SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneStatusUnknown";
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidArgument:        return @"SpeechClientStatus_InvalidArgument";
    }
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Unknown error: %d\n", errorCode];
}

/* Called when an error is received. */
-(void)onError:(NSString*)errorMessage withErrorCode:(int)errorCode
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self startButton] setEnabled:YES];
        [textOnScreen appendString:(@"********* Error Detected *********\n")];
        [textOnScreen appendFormat:(@"%@ %@\n"), errorMessage, ConvertSpeechErrorToString(errorCode)];
        self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen;
    });
}

/* Event fired when the microphone recording status has changed. */
-(void)onMicrophoneStatus:(Boolean)recording
{
    if (!recording) {
        [micClient endMicAndRecognition];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!recording) {
            [[self startButton] setEnabled:YES];
        }

        self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen;
    });
}

/* Create a recognition request to interact with the Speech Recognition Service.*/
-(void)initializeRecoClient
{
NSString* language = @"en-us";
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString* primaryOrSecondaryKey = [settings objectForKey:(@"primaryKey")];
NSString* luisAppID = [settings objectForKey:(@"luisAppID")];
NSString* luisSubscriptionID = [settings objectForKey:(@"luisSubscriptionID")];

if (isMicrophoneReco) {
    if (!isIntent) {
        micClient = [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createMicrophoneClient:(recoMode)
                                                               withLanguage:(language)
                                                                    withKey:(primaryOrSecondaryKey)
                                                               withProtocol:(self)];
    }
    else {
        MicrophoneRecognitionClientWithIntent* micIntentClient;
        micIntentClient = [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createMicrophoneClientWithIntent:(language)
                                                                                    withKey:(primaryOrSecondaryKey)
                                                                              withLUISAppID:(luisAppID)
                                                                             withLUISSecret:(luisSubscriptionID)
                                                                               withProtocol:(self)];
        micClient = micIntentClient;
    }
}
else {
    if (!isIntent) {
        dataClient = [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createDataClient:(recoMode)
                                                          withLanguage:(language)
                                                               withKey:(primaryOrSecondaryKey)
                                                          withProtocol:(self)];
    }
    else {
        DataRecognitionClientWithIntent* dataIntentClient;
        dataIntentClient = [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createDataClientWithIntent:(language)
                                                                               withKey:(primaryOrSecondaryKey)
                                                                         withLUISAppID:(luisAppID)
                                                                        withLUISSecret:(luisSubscriptionID)
                                                                          withProtocol:(self)];
        dataClient = dataIntentClient;
    }
}
}

/* Take enum value and produce NSString */
NSString* ConvertSpeechRecoConfidenceEnumToString(Confidence confidence)
{
switch (confidence) {
    case SpeechRecoConfidence_None:
        return @"None";

    case SpeechRecoConfidence_Low:
        return @"Low";

    case SpeechRecoConfidence_Normal:
        return @"Normal";

    case SpeechRecoConfidence_High:
        return @"High";
}
}

/* Action for pressing the "Start" button */
-(IBAction)startButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [textOnScreen setString:(@"")];
    self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen;
    [[self startButton] setEnabled:NO];

    if (isMicrophoneReco) {
        OSStatus status = [micClient startMicAndRecognition];
        if (status) {
            [textOnScreen appendFormat:(@"Error starting audio. %@\n"), ConvertSpeechErrorToString(status)];
        }
    }
}

/* Action for low memory */
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

I am new in ios programming. I will appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but what's the issue?

Comment: I ll post conversion issues tonight.

Comment: when I converted to .swift file. The first error I have is "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol'" at the following line: "class ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {"

Answer (score 0):

1. Please convert your objective-c view controller to swift. Dont import it via bridging-header.

   2.use the new converted class same as u were using previously in objective-c version

   3.just import frame work header files in bridging header.

To convert objective-c code to swift use [swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

> EDIT

**Here is the converted Code**

Both Files Are Combined

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {

//variable declaration.
var textOnScreen: NSMutableString
var dataClient: DataRecognitionClient
var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient
var recoMode: SpeechRecognitionMode
var isMicrophoneReco: Bool
var isIntent: Bool
var waitSeconds: Int

//IBOutlets
@IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton!
/* In our UI, we have a text box to show the reco results.*/
@IBOutlet var startButton: UITextView!

//IBAction

/* Action for pressing the "Start" button */

@IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    textOnScreen.string = ("")
    self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen
    self.startButton().enabled = false
    if isMicrophoneReco {
        var status: OSStatus = micClient.startMicAndRecognition()
        if status != nil {
            textOnScreen.appendFormat(("Error starting audio. %@\n"), ConvertSpeechErrorToString(status))
        }
    }

}
/* Initialization to be done when app starts. */

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textOnScreen = NSMutableString(capacity: 1000)
    recoMode = SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase
    isMicrophoneReco = true
    isIntent = false
    waitSeconds = recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase ? 20 : 200
    self.initializeRecoClient()
}

/* Action for low memory */

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

/* Called when a partial response is received. */

func onPartialResponseReceived(response: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        textOnScreen.appendFormat(("%@\n"), response)
        self.quoteText.text = response
    })
}

/* Called when a final response is received. */

func onFinalResponseReceived(response: RecognitionResult) {
    var isFinalDicationMessage: Bool = recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_LongDictation && (response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus_EndOfDictation || response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus_DictationEndSilenceTimeout)
    if isMicrophoneReco && ((recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage) {
        micClient.endMicAndRecognition()
    }
    if (recoMode == SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.startButton().enabled = true
        })
    }
}



func ConvertSpeechErrorToString( errorCode :Int) -> String
{
    switch errorCode as! SpeechClientStatus {
    case SpeechClientStatus_SecurityFailed:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_SecurityFailed"
    case SpeechClientStatus_LoginFailed:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_LoginFailed"
    case SpeechClientStatus_Timeout:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_Timeout"
    case SpeechClientStatus_ConnectionFailed:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_ConnectionFailed"
    case SpeechClientStatus_NameNotFound:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_NameNotFound"
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidService:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_InvalidService"
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidProxy:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_InvalidProxy"
    case SpeechClientStatus_BadResponse:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_BadResponse"
    case SpeechClientStatus_InternalError:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_InternalError"
    case SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationError:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationError"
    case SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationExpired:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_AuthenticationExpired"
    case SpeechClientStatus_LimitsExceeded:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_LimitsExceeded"
    case SpeechClientStatus_AudioOutputFailed:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_AudioOutputFailed"
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneInUse:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneInUse"
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneUnavailable:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneUnavailable"
    case SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneStatusUnknown:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneStatusUnknown"
    case SpeechClientStatus_InvalidArgument:
        return "SpeechClientStatus_InvalidArgument"

    }
    return String(format: "Unknown error: %d\n", errorCode)

}

/* Called when an error is received. */

func onError(errorMessage: String, withErrorCode errorCode: Int) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        self.startButton().enabled = true
        textOnScreen.appendString(("********* Error Detected *********\n"))
        textOnScreen.appendFormat(("%@ %@\n"), errorMessage, ConvertSpeechErrorToString(errorCode))
        self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen
    })
}


/* Event fired when the microphone recording status has changed. */

func onMicrophoneStatus(recording: Boolean) {
    if !recording {
        micClient.endMicAndRecognition()
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        if !recording {
            self.startButton().enabled = true
        }
        self.quoteText.text = textOnScreen
    })
}




func ConvertSpeechRecoConfidenceEnumToString( confidence:Confidence) -> String
{

    switch confidence {
    case SpeechRecoConfidence_None:
        return "None"
    case SpeechRecoConfidence_Low:
        return "Low"
    case SpeechRecoConfidence_Normal:
        return "Normal"
    case SpeechRecoConfidence_High:
        return "High"
    }
}

/* Create a recognition request to interact with the Speech Recognition Service.*/

override func initializeRecoClient() {



    var language: String = "en-us"
    var path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("settings", ofType: "plist")
    var settings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSObject : AnyObject](contentsOfFile: path)
    var primaryOrSecondaryKey: String = (settings[("primaryKey")] as! String)
    var luisAppID: String = (settings[("luisAppID")] as! String)
    var luisSubscriptionID: String = (settings[("luisSubscriptionID")] as! String)

    if isMicrophoneReco {
        if !isIntent {
            micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(withLanguage as! recoMode, : withKey as! language, : withProtocol as! primaryOrSecondaryKey, : (self))
        }
        else {
            var micIntentClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClientWithIntent
            micIntentClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClientWithIntent(withKey as! language, : withLUISAppID as! primaryOrSecondaryKey, : withLUISSecret as! luisAppID, : withProtocol as! luisSubscriptionID, : (self))
            micClient = micIntentClient
        }
    }

    else if !isIntent {
        dataClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createDataClient(withLanguage as! recoMode, : withKey as! language, : withProtocol as! primaryOrSecondaryKey, : (self))
    }
    else {
        var dataIntentClient: DataRecognitionClientWithIntent
        dataIntentClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createDataClientWithIntent(withKey as! language, : withLUISAppID as! primaryOrSecondaryKey, : withLUISSecret as! luisAppID, : withProtocol as! luisSubscriptionID, : (self))
        dataClient = dataIntentClient
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I did try swifty to convert [ObjectiveCViewController.mm](https://oxfordportal.blob.core.windows.net/example-speech/ViewController.mm) to ViewController.swift. However, I got some unrecognized member errors. can you help converting this link?

Comment: I will post the combined code for ObjrctiveCViewController.h and .mm tonight. AppDelegate files are are easily converted (generic). 

     
If you want build and run the given example, find the project embedded [here](https://www.projectoxford.ai/SDK/GetFile?path=speech/SpeechToText-SDK-iOS.zip) at samples\SpeechRecognitionServerExample
 into XCode.

Comment: @antbithia Do you want me to convert whole .m file for you or you need my on any specific block of code??

Comment: Almost all of it except for (void)onIntentReceived and (void)doDataRecognition. isMicrophoneReco needs to be set to true (isMicrophoneReco = true). Thanks.

Comment: Ok will Update you once completed with conversion. can you please explain where did you get unrecognized member errors?

Comment: I can update you tonight. I also converted .h header file and combined with .m file in .swift. I might be missing a framework file. Basically, when startButton tapped, it will convert microphone recognized speech to text and show in the quoteText label. Thanks.

Comment: when you are done just update me with your recent copy of code which i can access easily.

Comment: Harshal - I edited my original question and added recent copy of .h and .m files above.  I probably don't know how to combine them in .Swift file.

Comment: @antbithia Please Check The Updated Answer With Converted Code

Comment: still working on it. I had to link SpeechSDK.Framework from Objective-C.  Its header file is imported in the bridging file.  Some reason this module is not  recognized in the ViewController.Swift. I am getting error at `class  ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {` line as "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol'".  Help!

Comment: – onPartialResponseReceived: required method

– onIntentReceived: required method

– onFinalResponseReceived: required method

– onError:withErrorCode: required method

– onMicrophoneStatus: required method
 you have to implement above all methods u might be missing ?

Comment: – onIntentReceived: required method thats y error is there implement it also

Comment: I am having hard time to grasping this. would you provide me one example how to use required method for those protocol functions?

Comment: just implement onIntentReceived

Comment: finally working. I did multiple changes  (1) bridging file has 
`#import "SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h"` (2) removed SpeechRecognitionProtocol from ViewController.Swift   `class ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {` line, and  (3) fixed all bugs in the ViewController.Swift; i.e. changed  `SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase` to `SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase`.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome please let me know if any help required.

Let me know when you ready with full working demo.

I would love to test it.

Comment: I received Class ViewController has no initializers error and fixed following line by ending with "!" mark: 
`var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient!`
then I got nil error for micClient.startMicAndRecognition() in the startButtonTapped() function.  Trying to resolve this issue now. 
`var status: OSStatus = micClient.startMicAndRecognition`

Comment: give ? infront of all variable in start of class

Comment: var textOnScreen: NSMutableString
var dataClient: DataRecognitionClient
var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient
var recoMode: SpeechRecognitionMode
var isMicrophoneReco: Bool
var isIntent: Bool
var waitSeconds: Int

Comment: Thanks I will try this thing now tonight and let you know.

Comment: ok I added ? to: `var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient?` and I clicked on the Start Button but I got following error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)** inside `func startButtonTapped`  the function at `let status: OSStatus = micClient!.startMicAndRecognition()` and debugger shows **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**. This is probably related to initializing startMicAndRecognition() method.

Comment: The main issue could be recognizing Objective C framework into swift and get the import recognized. I set SpeechSDK framework "optional" not "required" to avoid "SpeechSDK is not loaded" error at the startup. In addition, All dependencies of the framework need to be specified in the Bridging Header file as well. I.e. #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> . I will try these tonight.

Comment: I added all dependencies of SpeechSDK framework to the bridging header file and SpeechSDK is set back to "Required". Startup error is gone but now I am getting **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"** at **micClient!.startMicAndRecognition()** line inside startButtonTapped function. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Sorry for late reply i was busy in other work.Please initiate micClient in viewdidload or before using it. It's giving error as it nil while accessing it.

Comment: The object is not getting allocated please check

Comment: I initialized micClient with MicrophoneRecognitionClient() and I am no longer getting fatal error. I am getting this error **AudioStart@144 originating error 0x80070057 from AudioStart 144**. I guess I need to find a way SpeechRecognitionProtocol to conform with ViewController class to implement the required Speech API methods. So they are functional.

Comment: Can you rate up the answer

Comment: i did but it says once you earn 15 reputation, your vote will change publicity displayed.