# Fatal Error when connectting Objective-C framework to Swift iOS project (SpeechSDK framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api, speech-recognition

I converted an Objective-C Speech Recognition API Swift as is.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {
var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient
var isMicrophoneReco: Bool

/* Action for pressing the "Start" button */
@IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isMicrophoneReco {
        var status: OSStatus = micClient.startMicAndRecognition()
    }
}
```

I got following errors:

**Type 'ViewController' does not conform to 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol'** 
**Class 'ViewController' has no initializers**

I fixed as following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient?
var isMicrophoneReco: Bool = true

/* Action for pressing the "Start" button */
@IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isMicrophoneReco {
        var status: OSStatus = micClient!.startMicAndRecognition()
    }
}
```

I am getting

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)** at

```
micClient!.startMicAndRecognition()
```

line inside startButtonTapped function. Apparently, when converting Objective-C based APIs, it is common for values to be declared as an optional although they are always expected to return a value. But Swift requires to initialize variables.

I am working on this for days now.  How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: Show the Objective-C declaration of SpeechRecognitionProtocol please

Comment: sorry missed your question here. [The protocol is declared in the ViewController.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471902/convert-microsoft-project-oxford-speech-recognition-from-objective-c-to-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The first error:

**Type 'ViewController' does not conform to 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol' Class**

is saying that your class declares that it conforms to the `SpeechRecognitionProtocol` but does not implement the required method(s). 
I can only guess that `SpeechRecognitionProtocol` is from [here](https://www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/ios/Protocols/SpeechRecognitionProtocol.html), and you are not implementing all the required methods.
Simply removing it fixes the compile-time error, but you lose the `SpeechRecognitionProtocol` functionality, and that depends on whether you want it or not.

The second error:

**'ViewController' has no initializers**

is because all instance variables in swift must either be initialised when they are declared, or initialised in their class init method, or declare optional (or as implicitly-unwrapped optionals).

Your fix for this second error was to declare `micClient` as optional. However in `startButtonTapped` you force-unwrap it, and since you don't initialise `micClient` anywhere, it is nil, and you get your run-time exception.
To fix this, you need to initialise `micClient` at some point.

Comment: You may have imported `SpeechRecognitionService` fine, but to implement the protocol, you need to add the delegate methods in your view controller. That is to say, look at the `SpeechRecognitionService` declaration to see what are the required methods, and add all them to your view controller class.
`var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient?` is _not_ an initialisation, it's a _declaration_. An initialisation would be `var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient? = MicrophoneRecognitionClient()` or something similar.

Comment: I have bridge header file containing all dependent header files #import "SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h". All of its methods are complied fine. How can implement SpeechRecognitionProtocol? Secondly How can I initialize micClient?. Thanks

Comment: @antbithia you still have not done what I asked you to do, i.e. show the SpeechRecognitionProtocol declaration. We don't know what it looks like so we can't translate it into Swift terms for you. Show it!

Comment: I added `= MicrophoneRecognitionClient()` and I am no longer getting fatal error. I am getting this error but I can work on this  **AudioStart@144 originating error 0x80070057 from AudioStart 144**

Comment: matt- sorry missed your question above. [The protocol is declared in the ViewController.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471902/convert-microsoft-project-oxford-speech-recognition-from-objective-c-to-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var status: OSStatus = micClient!.startMicAndRecognition()
```

`!` Means you are force unwrapping this object and if it is not there it will break so you could wrap it in a `guard` statement or an `if let` So before that line do something like this

```
 guard let client = micClient as?  MicrophoneRecognitionClient else {
      NSAssertFailure("error No MicrophoneClient")
 }
 client.startMicAndRecognition()
```